# looping a list through a dictionary in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I realize there are other questions similar to this, but I'm not quite getting it.

Let's say there's a dictionary:

```
fav_food = {'jen':'pizza','eric':'burrito','jason':'spaghetti','tom':'mac'}
```

and then there's a list:

```
users = ['jason', 'phil', 'jen', 'ben']
```

The scenario here is that

```
if a user in the list 'users' is in the dict. 'fav_food.keys()',  
then print(the user + " likes" + fav_food[the user])  
if a user in the list 'users' is not in the dict. 'fav_food.keys()',  
then print(the user + " hasn't taken the poll")
```

the return should be:

```
Jason likes Spaghetti  
Phil hasn't taken the poll  
Jen likes Pizza  
Ben hasn't taken the poll
```

I wanted to use the loop 'for' and somehow iterate a list through a dictionary... but I keep getting error no matter what I do.
I'd prefer to do it the most "Python" way, if possible.

I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
for user in users:
    if user in fav_food.keys():
        print(user.capitalize(),"likes",fav_food[user].capitalize())
    else:
        print(user.capitalize(),"hasn't taken the poll")
```

This will output as-

```
Jason likes Spaghetti
Phil hasn't taken the poll
Jen likes Pizza
Ben hasn't taken the poll
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it this way and it worked. It's what I had in mind logically. Definitely readable this way too!

Comment: You don't need to do `in fav_food.keys()`, you can simply do `in fav_food`.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like

```
for user in users:
    try:
        print('{} likes {}'.format(user, fav_food[user]))
    except KeyError:
        print("{} hasn't taken the poll".format(user))
```

That would iterate over all users and if there is no *fav food* for a particular user, then it just print what you've said.

Comment: an `if` statement would do. There is no need for `try-except` here.

Comment: Consider me old-school ☺. Anyway +1

Comment: @vishes_shell wow, thanks for the answer. I tried it the way you suggested and it worked. I guess, as a beginner, I wanted to tackle this with 'if' statement, but this way does feel a lot like the python way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
fav_food = {'jen':'pizza','eric':'burrito','jason':'spaghetti','tom':'mac'}  
users = ['jason', 'phil', 'jen', 'ben'] 

for user in users:
    print(f"{user} likes {fav_food[user]}" if fav_food.get(user, None) else f"{user} hasn't taken the poll yet")
```

Works like a charm, but worth keeping in mind that if a user were to have an empty string as their favourite food it would instead say that they had not take the poll